# Brainstorm - Slow Query from Plugin Need to Speed It Up

Tags: plugin-development, query, mysql

We use WP as the backend for a business directory. I have a plugin that queries based upon location coordinates looking for the closest 10 locations to a given "listing". This query is really slow (like 1.5-2 seconds average) but it is really valuable and important information. Before I get into coding for a solution I figured I would throw out the question here and see how you would suggest handling it.

A sample page can be found here [Dev Server Listing](http://cgvws.staging.wpengine.com/parks/us/massachusetts/foxboro-ma/normandy-farms-family-camping-resort/) You will see the problem results at the bottom flagged as "Posts Nearby". This list is generated using GEO Mashup [Plugin](http://www.google.com/url?q=https://wordpress.org/plugins/geo-mashup/&sa=U&ei=k9dJVLXhGIiNNpzJgugL&ved=0CBQQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNF6nJ5XHpflkAXzo4KurgMpOSbKBw)

In this example here is the query that ran:

```sql
SELECT
  gmlr.object_id,
  gmlr.geo_date,
  o.post_title   AS label,
  gml.*,
  o.post_author,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.lat,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.lng,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.address,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.saved_name,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.postal_code,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.admin_code,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.sub_admin_code,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.country_code,
  wp_geo_mashup_locations.locality_name,
  6371 * 2 * ASIN(
      SQRT(
          POWER(
              SIN(
                  RADIANS(42.0396996 - wp_geo_mashup_locations.lat) / 2
              ),
              2
          )
          + COS(
                RADIANS(42.0396996)
            )
            * COS(
              RADIANS(wp_geo_mashup_locations.lat)
          ) * POWER(
              SIN(
                  RADIANS(-71.2824554 - wp_geo_mashup_locations.lng)
                  / 2
              ),
              2
          )
      )
  ) AS distance_km
FROM wp_geo_mashup_locations gml INNER JOIN
  wp_geo_mashup_location_relationships gmlr
    ON gmlr.object_name = 'post' AND gmlr.location_id = gml.id
  INNER JOIN wp_posts o ON o.ID = gmlr.object_id
  INNER JOIN wp_geo_mashup_location_relationships
    ON wp_geo_mashup_location_relationships.object_id = o.ID
  INNER JOIN wp_geo_mashup_locations
    ON wp_geo_mashup_locations.id = wp_geo_mashup_location_relationships.location_id
WHERE post_status = 'publish'
      AND o.post_type IN ('listing', 'post', 'page', 'attachment', 'product', 'transaction')
      AND gmlr.object_id NOT IN (7251) AND (
        wp_geo_mashup_location_relationships.object_name = 'post' AND
        wp_geo_mashup_locations.lat > 41.314769646 AND
        wp_geo_mashup_locations.lng > -72.2585540753 AND
        wp_geo_mashup_locations.lat < 42.764629554 AND
        wp_geo_mashup_locations.lng < -70.3063567247)
GROUP BY o.ID
HAVING distance_km < 80.4672248946
ORDER BY distance_km ASC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

```
/* From path/to/request/uri/ in 
   [/wp-content/plugins/geo-mashup/geo-mashup-db.php:1670] */

CALL FROM :REQUIRE('wp-blog-header.php'),
require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
include('/themes/vantage/wrapper.php'),
load_template,
require_once('/themes/vantage/single-listing.php'),
GeoMashup::nearby_list,
GeoMashupSearch->__construct,
GeoMashupSearch-> QUERY,
GeoMashupDB::get_object_locations
```

Any thoughts, suggestions, or guidance is appreciated. How can we speed this up?

Comment: You'll need to contact the plugin author. Third party plugins are off topic here. Post this question on the wordpress.org support forum. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slow queries need to be cached, and the cache probably should be primed when the post is being saved to keep high level of responsiveness for all users (except for the one submitting the post at the time of submitting).